# SQL Sum Up Values by Group

Tags: sql, sum

I have a following table person_amounts.

```
Person_id     Item_Amount   
 1             50
 1             10
 1             10
 1             20
 2             30
 2             40
 2             40
```

I want to write a query so that a new column Total is the sum of items by person.  So the result would be:

```
 Person_id     Item_Amount   Total
 1             50            90
 1             10            90
 1             10            90
 1             20            90
 2             30            110
 2             40            110
 2             40            110
```

I could write something like:

```
select person_id, item_amount, (select sum(item_amount) from person_amounts pa 
where pa.person_id = p.person_id) Total from person_amounts p
```

However, the problem is that this query will sum up all the rows in my table for each person id.  This will cause a problem if I add a where condition to limit the data.  I am looking to have the Total column populate the sum based on the rows that are in my result.  So if I add a where condition like

```
where item_amount >= 20
```

I'd like the results to show the following:

```
 Person_id     Item_Amount   Total
 1             50            70
 1             20            70
 2             30            110
 2             40            110
 2             40            110
```

Comment: `select person_id, item_amount, sum(item_amount) over (partition by person_id order by person_id) as total from person_amounts where item_amount >=20`

Comment: I think that's a good answer, but you don't need the ORDER BY in a windowed SUM (at least not in SQL Server/t-sql). It will still work though.

Comment: Agree, thanks for pointing it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply want a window function:

```
select person_id, item_amount,
       sum(item_amount) over (partition by person_id)
from person_amounts pa 
where item_amount >= 20;
```

Window functions are standard SQL supported by basically all databases.

If you want to use a subquery -- which is less performant and more verbose -- then you need to filter the results in the subquery as well as in the outer query.